# Prove $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=\lfloor \frac{1}{n}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm reading a direct proof for mobius inversion theorem but I don’t know how the writer make the assumption that $$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)= \Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigr\rfloor$$

Can someone please explain and prove this?

Comment: There are proofs on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_function#Proof_of_the_formula_for_∑d|n_μ(d))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

$$\left\lfloor\frac1n\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=1\\
0,&\text{if }n>0\,,
\end{cases}$$

so this is just a fancy way of saying that

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=1\\
0,&\text{if }n>0\,.
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

By definition $\mu(1)=1$, so $(1)$ holds for $n=1$. If $p$ is any prime,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{d\mid p^k}\mu(d)&=\sum_{i=0}^k\mu(p^i)\\
&=\mu(1)+\mu(p)+\sum_{i=2}^k\mu(p^i)\\
&=1+(-1)+0\\
&=0\,.
\end{align*}$$

The result now follows from the fact that $\mu$ is multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

When **$n=1$** we have $$\sum_{ d|n} \mu(d)=\mu(1)=1$$.

When **$n>1$**, then write $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \dots p_k^{a_k}$, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
   \sum_{ d|n} \mu(d)&=\sum_{ 0 \leq b_i \leq a_i} \mu(p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2} \dots p_k^{b_k})\\
 &=\mu(1)+\mu(p_1)+\dots \mu(p_n)+\mu(p_1p_2)\dots \mu(p_{n-1}p_n)+\dots\mu(p_1 \dots p_n)\\
 &=1(-1)^0+{n \choose 1}(-1)^1+{n \choose 2}(-1)^2+{n \choose 3}(-1)^3+ \dots {n \choose n}(-1)^n \\
 &=(1-1)^n \\
 &=0.
 \end{align*}$$
Hence $$\sum_{ d|n} \mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=1\\
0,&\text{if }n>0\
\end{cases}=\left\lfloor\frac1n\right\rfloor$$

This proves your result. Note that this proof doesn't assume the multiplicative property.